# Kill/stop a busy FutureTask Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to get an Auth ticket from a 3rd party server. I am using FutureTask to perform the task. However, if I don't get response from the server after 10 seconds, I want to timeout the call. At the same time, I want to kill the Thread which was busy in fetching the Auth Ticket from 3rd party, but got stuck because of some issue. Here is the simplified code.

```
public String getAuthTicket(final String userName) throws Exception{
    String authTicket=null;
    final FutureTask<String> future =
            new FutureTask<String>(new Callable<String>() {
                public String call() throws Exception {                             
                    log.info("calling server to get trusted ticket.");                                              
                    if(Thread.interrupted()){
                        log.info("Call to server got interrupted.");
                        return "-1";
                    }
                    String authTicket = getTrustedTicket(userName);
                    return authTicket;
                }
            });

    final Thread thread = new Thread(future);
    thread.start(); 
    String authTicket ="-1";    

    try {
        authTicket = future.get(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        log.info("authTicket: "+ authTicket);
        return authTicket;
    } catch (Exception e){
        log.warning("Timeout occured while waiting to get auth ticket: Reason:"+ e);
        future.cancel(true);            
    }

    return authTicket;
}
```

Could anyone please review my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of starting a new thread you can instead create a executor which will take `Runnables` and reuse threads as needed. you can create a executor usign one of the [`Executors`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html)' static factories.

This code relies on `getTrustedTicket()` responding correctly to a thread interruption. Which you didn't include so I can't judge it. (A lot of IO functions don't respond to it by default).

The catch-all when waiting on the result is not a great thing. You should instead catch only the specific exceptions you can get and only declare those you throw.

```
try {
    authTicket = future.get(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    log.info("authTicket: "+ authTicket);
    return authTicket;
} catch (InterruptedException e){
    log.warning("Current thread interrupted while waiting to get auth ticket: Reason:"+ e);
    future.cancel(true);
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); //reset interrupted state or rethrow the exception.
} catch (ExecutionException e){
    log.warning("Exception occured getting the auth ticket: Reason:"+ e.getCause());
} catch (TimeoutException e){
    log.warning("Timeout occurred while waiting to get auth ticket: Reason:"+ e);
    future.cancel(true);
}
```